# Canada visit visa for 15 days how much bank balance required

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, proof-provenance-of-funds

How much bank balance required for Canada visit visa. 
For one person or with MY wife and one six years daughter.

And for one person how much need From Dubai UAE. I am Indian passport holder.

Comment: "How large a bank balance" is generally the **wrong question to ask**. It's not a matter of the balance. See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: You should already have worked out how much your trip will cost you. If you have, then you know how much you need. If you haven't then you need to do so.

Answer (score 3):

There is no published requirement. The Government of Canada website https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eligibility.html states:
“You must have enough money for your stay

- The amount of money you will need depends on how long you will stay and if you will stay in a hotel, or with friends or relatives.”

You can get an idea of how much to budget for your trip from sites such as https://www.budgetyourtrip.com/canada, but really it depends on your financial circumstances and what you propose to do during the trip.